# Extracting Role of user From Jwt tokens i am getting from spring boot in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

actually i am working on spring boot and reacts js.I am getting jWT token from spring boot like:-

token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTI5NjI4NTAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiM2U4YzQ2NGYtZjYzMy00ZjUxLTg4MzktM2U4YjI5NmViOGZlIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoibGl2ZS10ZXN0Iiwic2NvcGUiOlsiYXBwIl19.TwQMMRfqJ6tv6v6_8hY7vUoFXoF_OU684SLD6bRZhag

and i want to extract the role of user  like Admin , customer or seller from jwt token i am getting in react. Is it possible

Comment: You can implement an API in your spring-boot project /userinfo to get the current user profile , username , role etc .. by sending the token

Answer (score 0):

Yup! A package like [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) would do the trick.